# Fortify shows critical vulnerability File.Delete() operation C#

Tags: c#, fortify, path-manipulation

The following code always shows path manipulation problem. How to resolve it ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace PathManipulation
{
    class Program
    {
       public string dir = null;
       public void someFunction(string fileName)
        {

          //  File.Delete(Regex.Replace(dir + fileName, @"\..\", String.Empty));
            if (!(dir.IndexOf("//") >= 0) || !Regex.IsMatch(dir, "System32"))
            {
                String p = Regex.Replace(dir, @"..\", string.Empty);
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(p);
                FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();
                if (fi.Length > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fi[i].ToString().Equals(fileName))
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(fi[i].ToString());
                            fi[i].Delete();
                        }
                    }
                    File.Delete(dir + fileName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }


        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Program p = new Program();
           p.dir = args[0];
           p.someFunction(args[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and the resulting problem?

Comment: String p = Regex.Replace(dir, @"..\", string.Empty); What are you trying to acomplish with this line?

Comment: In my code I am trying to delete a file within a directory. Both directory and filename are variable. The fortify scan always reports a path manipulation vulnerability in my code. This is not actual code but reproes the problem. I have tried to check some mal pattern in input with string checks. Still the problem remains, is there any safe way to delete a file and satisfy Fortify ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you break the flow of data so that the end user is not able to specify the file to be deleted.

For instance:

```
public void someFunction(int fileIndex){
...
   if (fileIndex == 0){
      File.Delete( "puppies.txt" );
   }
   else if (fileIndex == 1){
      File.Delete( "kittens.txt" );
   }
   else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Invalid delete index" );
   }
}
```

That's an extreme way to solve the problem, but it does not allow the end user to delete ANYTHING the developer didn't intend.

Your data validation check:

```
if (!(dir.IndexOf("//") >= 0) || !Regex.IsMatch(dir, "System32"))
```

is weak. This is referred to as "blacklisting" and the attacker only has to figure out a pattern that is missed by your checks.  So, @"C:\My Documents" for instance.

Instead, you should consider a "whitelisting" approach.  Take a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation#Accept_known_good for a pretty thorough example.  It doesn't address path injection directly.  You simply have to think hard about what files/directories you expect to receive.  Throw an error if the input deviates from that.  With a little testing you will create a good whitelist.